# Matlab: Classify random vector w.r.t. equally spaced vector of different size

Tags: matlab, range, classification, histogram, member

```
A=[0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1]; % generated by random numbers, these are representative values. A can take any value.
B=0:1/10:1; % 10 divisions to divide line element
```

A is always a randomly produced vector and B is fixed vector. A's values are to be compared with B's values. A is to be modified such that if value belong to class of B then it is kept in that class, otherwise zero is assigned.

The expected output is

```
A=[0.1,0,0.3,0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8,0.9,1.0]; % Size of A increases here.
```

Comment: Is A randomly selected only from the same set as B? That is, .15 would not be allowed? Are repeats in A allowed?

Comment: Do you really mean `B=0:1/9:1`, or maybe `B=0:1/10:1`? Otherwise I don't see the logic

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
result = B.*ismembertol(B,A,1e-6);
```

This keeps entries of `B` that are very close to some entry of `A`, and makes the rest zero.

Note that I say "very close to" (and use [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html)) rather than "equal to" (which would correspond to [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)), otherwise you might get false negatives because of numerical precision. The argument `1e-6` is a *relative tolerance*, that you should choose depending on your needs.

Comment: @user9003011 It doesn't match because I still can't get the logic of what you want (that's why I wrote "I _think_ you want..."): why is the `0` in `B` not present in the output?